# $PYTHONSTARTUP with python 2.7 and python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, startupscript

I finally started using python 3 alongside python 2.7 on Linux.

I setup my python shell using a startup-script defined by $PYTHONSTARTUP.
Due to incompatibilities I am unable to use the same script for both versions.

What is the easiest way to get one script for python 2.7, and another for python 3.2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use Python 2 for some projects and Python 3 for others, then change the environment variable when you change projects.

Or, have your startup script look like this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    import startup2
else:
    import startup3
```

and split your real startup code into `startup2.py` and `startup3.py`

Comment: I went for the startup-script option, and wrote something similar to your code. I picked this answer because it was the first to suggest this solution.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'versioninfo'`. It's supposed to be `version_info`.

Answer (score 7):

Set your $PYTHONSTARTUP to point to a script like this, which checks the version of Python being used, and then delegates to another startup script:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0]==2:
    from startup2k import *
elif sys.version_info[0]==3:
    from startup3k import *
else:
    # logging.warn('Unsupported version of Python')
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Define an alias for one of the python versions. In the alias, reset PYTHONSTARTUP as appropriate for that python version:

```
alias py3='PYTHONSTARTUP=/path/to/startup.py /other/path/to/python3.2'
```