# Disable .pythonrc only in Python 2

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

Thanks to this assignment:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc
```

I can start an initialization script as soon as I run Python, a bit like the .bashrc file. The problem is that this works on both Python2 and Python3, instead I want to prevent Python2 from doing this, due to hassles with code in .pythonrc.
I know I can put an If in the .pythonrc file to block its execution in Python2, but I would like to avoid doing this and stop it from running the script in the bud.
Is there a possible way to do this or an alternative variable that works only with Python3 equivalent to `PYTHONSTARTUP` (eg. `PYTHON3STARTUP`)?
All solutions that allow me not to insert code inside the .pythonrc file are accepted.
Even an answer that says that this way does not exist (citing a source or providing evidence) is accepted.

Why do I want a solution that is outside of the script?
I'll explain it to you with an example:

```
def python_major_version():
    import sys
    return sys.version_info.major

python_major_version = python_major_version()

if python_major_version == 3:
    # Incompatible syntax block with Python2
```

The scope of the sys module is only inside the function, as I want.
`python_major_version = python_major_version()`: This is my method of assigning the Python version number to a variable, without importing the `sys` module.

When I run Python2 from the terminal, despite the `If` that prevents the block from being executed, the syntax of all the code is still checked, giving me the error of `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: This really sounds like a job for an `if`.

Comment: Nit: `sys` is imported. The only difference is that the *name* `sys` is bound in the function scope, not the global scope.

Comment: If you want Python-3-specific syntax, that will have to go into a separate module that is conditionally imported. A module or script has to be parsed as a whole before any part of it can be executed.

Comment: What is `Nit`?.

Comment: A minor issue in something you said. If you `import sys`, no matter where you run it, the module is imported. (In fact, `sys` and others are *built-in* modules in CPython, meaning the module is available whether you use `import` or not.)

Comment: This question has already interesting solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346984/pythonstartup-with-python-2-7-and-python-3-2), where the "isolating syntax" feature you require is handled either with a [sub-import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7347047/7212665), or by a [wrapper alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7347161/7212665).

Comment: Alias is not a good solution while the import would be a solution appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the import works only if file ending with .py extention and not begin with a point, then if in the startup file `.pythonrc` I put the code: `from .example import *`, with the script file called `.example.py`, the import doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a python script, so simply check sys.version:

```
# ~/.pythonrc
import sys
if (sys.version_info.major < 3):
    print('py2, do nothing')
    quit()
    

print('do something')
```

Comment: This is the solution they already know about. They specifically asked for something else.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question. How about an early quit()?

Comment: We too are mystified why they don't want this, but they clearly say they don't.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to prevent this outside of the script. Even an answer that says that this way does not exist (citing a source) is accepted.

Comment: PYTHONSTARTUP is an envvar shared by all python versions. So your best option would be to have a "first entry" file, that imports your specific config files (call them e.g. ~/.python36rc, ~/.python39rc, ~/.python27rc, etc.) depending on sys.version_info

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you don't want to open the file in py2, what you plan to do in this file, etc.

Comment: Another (bash) solution is to alias : `alias mypython3="PYTHONSTARTUP=~/pythonrc /usr/bin/python3"`, there are plenty of such possible tricks.

Comment: Ok, I have explain the motivation.